React native app opens google play no internet notice if opened in offline
App was working fine in offline mode, but suddenly it started opening google play app showing offline message.
Has anyone experience the same? And how can I fix it?
I tried to remove suspicious libraries but without any luck, happens only when app is downloaded from Google play.

Problem was in Google's new "Automatic integrity protection", if I enable this option in play console, than app isn't working in offline.

I disabled this option, but I am still facing the issue.

@MehmetPeker Did you upload the new version?

I disabled the option after installing the release bundle but I hadn't released it yet so it didn't work.it works after installing a new version.thanks
